# How to paste a set of values as text instead of calculation into an excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, copy-paste

I am trying to paste the following values into one Excel cell

```
-0.00539916  -0.0150491  -0.0118165  -0.0187344 -0.00907009  -0.0120633
```

However, I always got a value of `-0.07213`, which is the calculation. So how to display those values into one Excel cell without calculating them?

Comment: How are the values to be separated? Commas, spaces, semi-colons?

Comment: They are separated by spaces

Comment: Add a single apostrophe at the start, `'-0.00539916 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel tends to red numbers and think it knows what it's doing.  As you realize, this is often incorrect.  Quite simply, to show a string literally as entered, start with a single apostrophe, `'`.

If you want to show `00001` instead of just `1` (without other formatting), just enter `'00001`.  That first apostrophe won't show in the cell (only Formula bar).

So for your example, as mentioned, just add the apostrophe:

```
'-0.00539916  -0.0150491  -0.0118165  -0.0187344 -0.00907009  -0.0120633
```